# Is there a way of storing an array based on a model?

Tags: html, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to store all the new 'Aulas', but it only saves the first value on the database, can't manage to get it working. The new fields have an increment, as the first starts at 0. Any aproach or path to follow?

```
<div id="newAula">

                    <div class="inline-flex" id="containerAula0">
                        <div class="inline-block w-full mr-2">
                        <label class="text-sm font-bold text-center uppercase opacity-70">Título</label>
                        <input type="text" name="titulo_aula0" class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 rounded bg-slate-200" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="inline-block ml-2">
                        <label class="text-sm font-bold uppercase opacity-70">Video ID</label>
                        <input type="text" name="video_id0" class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 rounded bg-slate-200" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="inline-block mt-10 ml-2">
                        <button id="removeAula0" class="h-8 px-3 font-bold duration-300 ease-in-out rounded cursor-pointer text-newwhite bg-red" type="button">
                        X
                        </button>
                        </div>
                        <p class="my-3">
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline-flex" id="containerAula1"> <div class="inline-block w-full mr-2"> <label class="text-sm font-bold text-center uppercase opacity-70">Título</label> <input type="text" id="titulo_aula1" class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 rounded bg-slate-200" required=""> </div> <div class="inline-block ml-2"> <label class="text-sm font-bold uppercase opacity-70">Video ID</label> <input type="text" id="video_id1" class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 rounded bg-slate-200" required=""> </div> <div class="inline-block mt-10 ml-2"> <button id="removeAula1" class="h-8 px-3 font-bold duration-300 ease-in-out rounded cursor-pointer text-newwhite bg-red"> X </button> </div> <p class="my-3"></p></div><div class="inline-flex" id="containerAula2"> <div class="inline-block w-full mr-2"> <label class="text-sm font-bold text-center uppercase opacity-70">Título</label> <input type="text" id="titulo_aula2" class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 rounded bg-slate-200" required=""> </div> <div class="inline-block ml-2"> <label class="text-sm font-bold uppercase opacity-70">Video ID</label> <input type="text" id="video_id2" class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 rounded bg-slate-200" required=""> </div> <div class="inline-block mt-10 ml-2"> <button id="removeAula2" class="h-8 px-3 font-bold duration-300 ease-in-out rounded cursor-pointer text-newwhite bg-red"> X </button> </div> <p class="my-3"></p></div></div>
```

[image: visual part]

Controller:

```
        $modulo = Modulo::create([
            'nome' => $request->nome,
            'sinopse' => $request->sinopse,
            'tumbnail' => $request->thumbnail
        ]);

        $aula = Aula::create([
            'titulo' => $request->titulo,
            'video_id' => $request->video_id,
            'modulo_id' => $modulo->id,
        ]);

         if (request()->hasFile('thumbnail')) {
             $thumbnail = request()->file('thumbnail')->getClientOriginalName();
             request()->file('thumbnail')->storeAs('public/modulos/', $modulo->id . '/' . $thumbnail, '');
             $modulo->update(['thumbnail' => $thumbnail]);
         }
         dd($modulo, $aula);
```

When I DD, it shows off:
[image: DD where saves only one record]
Sorry for any rookie mistake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store array in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329267/how-to-store-array-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part:

```
<div class="inline-block w-full mr-2">
    <label class="text-sm font-bold text-center uppercase opacity-70">Título</label>
    <input type="text" name="titulo_aula0" class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 rounded bg-slate-200" required="">
</div>
<div class="inline-block ml-2">
    <label class="text-sm font-bold uppercase opacity-70">Video ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="video_id0" class="w-full p-3 mt-2 mb-4 rounded bg-slate-200" required="">
</div>
<div class="inline-block mt-10 ml-2">
    <button id="removeAula0" class="h-8 px-3 font-bold duration-300 ease-in-out rounded cursor-pointer text-newwhite bg-red" type="button">
         X
    </button>
</div>
```

You can name the inputs as an array like this instead of indexing:

```
<input type="text" name="titulo_aula[]">
<input type="text" name="video_id[]">
```

then you can get an array in Laravel like this and create an object for each array items:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($request->input('titulo_aula')); $i++)
    {
        $aula = Aula::create([
            'titulo' => $request->input('titulo_aula')[$i],
            'video_id' => $request->input('video_id')[$i],
            'modulo_id' => $modulo->id
        ]);
    }
```